# Reading args with spaces in node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

In discord.js I'm trying to read args having no space issues, for example:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {

run: async (client, message, args, { GuildDB }) => {
    let roleName = args[0];
    let roleColor = args[1];
},
};
```

Problem is, "roleName" doesn't allow to me to use spaces and it counts the second word as `roleColor` when I use spaces in `roleName`

How do I easy control args? splits? or use spaces between args?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `args`? `process.argv`? Some args passed by `discord.js`? Where are the arguments parsed from? Just a string message that's split by spaces?

Comment: Traditionally in console applications to pass a string with spaces as a single argument, you would enclose it in quotes (`"this is a single argument"`).

Comment: edited the code, apologize for making you confused, check again @cbr

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: Again, how is this `run` function used? Where do you pass the function? Who calls this function and passes it its arguments?

Comment: @cbr have you ever worked in discord.js before? you don't seem familiar with any of the codes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle how the array and split and joined.

To make this easier for yourslef I first recommend you switch the places of your arguments. `[command] [roleColor] [roleName]` instead of `[command] [roleName] [roleColor]`.

This way we can isolate the color and then use the remaining elements to assign and join to `roleName`

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    run: async (client, message, args, { GuildDB }) => {
        // Deconstruct from the args array
        let [roleColor, roleName] = [args[0], args.slice(1)];

        // If there are more than 1 element, join them into a string via a space
        roleName = roleName.join(' ');
    },
};
```

Comment: I got an error: `roleName.join is not a function` why is that so?

Comment: @Zuher Laith, My mistake, the rest operator is not needed for this method. I have edited and tested my answer and this should now work!

Comment: this works, although I didn't get to understand why we slize "arg[1]" and join it with a space?

Comment: Let's say we have the args array as `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` (Foo is color and Bar Baz is the name). To get the name we remove the color arg, which is done with `slice(1)` (Removes 1st element), leaving `['bar', 'baz']`. We use `join(' ')`  to join the 2 separate array elements together into a string which results in `'bar baz'`. Documentations for [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

Best thing you could do here is create a `TextChannel#createMessageCollector` since you have multiple arguments to get as input easiest way to do it would be like so: ( Example user command !createrole  )

```js
let rolename = args.join(" ") 
message.channel.send("Alright now what would be it's color?").then( msg => 
const filter = (m) => { m.author.id === message.author.id }
const collector = msg.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 15000 })
collector.on('collect', collected => {
message.channel.send(`Alright creating the role ${rolename} with color ${collected.first().content}`); 
message.guild.roles.create({
    name: rolename
    color: collected.first().content;
})
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me in discordjs@12.5.3

Comment: Does not work won't help me improve my answer , could you add further details such as errors n stuff?

Comment: Does not work won't help me improve my answer , could you add further details such as errors n stuff?

Comment: The code is not well formatted, it gives me errors on:
```Ln3 Col1 " const { expected "
Ln4 Col 78 " ',' expected "```
I couldn't get to format it correctly..

Comment: Fixed that, the first error doesnt seem valid since I am not destructuring anything although added { just for the sake of it maybe for the arrow function that is